# Extract substring with regex python

Tags: python, regex

I know this is a very frequently asked question, but it's driving me mad.

I want to use regex to match a substring in my string.

```
 line = '##ParameterValue[part I care about]=garbagegarbage'
```

And I would like to extract the `part I care about`.
My code looks like this:

```
import re
line = '##ParameterValue[part I care about]=garbagegarbage'
m = re.match('\[(.*)\]', line)
print m.group(1)
```

But this gives me an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

I tested my regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it works. I don't understand why this fails for me.

Comment: You are right, it is too frequent a question.

Comment: Try [`search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead. [`match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) is looking to match from beginning of the string.

Answer (score 9):

Change `match` to `search`

```
import re
line = '##ParameterValue[part I care about]=garbagegarbage'
m = re.search('\[(.*)\]', line)
print m.group(1)
```